# HttpContext null while testing controller

Tags: c#, testing, .net-core, integration-testing, xunit

I am trying to setup tests for my controller endpoints and I came up with this design after some research.

**Controller interface**

```
public interface IAuthenticationController
{
    Task<IActionResult> Login(AuthenticateUserDTO loginDto);
}
```

The interface is implemented in the controller class, that inherits `ControllerBase` and has `[ApiController]` attribute.

**BaseFixture.cs**

```
public class BaseFixture : WebApplicationFactory<TestStartup>
{
    private Lazy<HttpClient> client;

    public BaseFixture()
    {
        client = new Lazy<HttpClient>(() => Server.CreateClient());

        var repo = Server.Host.Services.GetRequiredService<IUserGestairRepository>();

        var task = repo.UserManager.CreateAsync(new User_Gestair()
        {
            UserName = "dev@dev.com.br",
            Email = "dev@dev.com.br"
        }, "123456");
        task.Wait();
        var result = task.Result;
    }

    protected override IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder()
    {
        return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .UseStartup<TestStartup>();
    }

    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {

        builder.ConfigureServices(services => 
        {
            var descriptor = services.SingleOrDefault(
            d => d.ServiceType ==
                typeof(DbContextOptions<GestairDbContext>));

            services.Remove(descriptor);

            services.AddDbContext<GestairDbContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
            });

            services.AddDefaultIdentity<User_Gestair>(options =>
            {
                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
                options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
                options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
                options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            })
            .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
            .AddErrorDescriber<IdentityErrorDescriber>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<GestairDbContext>();

            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
            services.AddHttpClient();

            services.AddTransient<IAspNetUser, AspNetUser>();
            services.AddMediatorConfiguration(typeof(CreateCompanyCommandHandler).Assembly);
            services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));
            services.AddScoped<ICompanyController, CompanyController>();
            services.AddScoped<IAuthenticationController, AuthenticationController>();
            services.AddScoped<ICompanyRepository, CompanyRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IUserGestairRepository, UserGestairRepository>();

            services.AddControllers()
             .AddApplicationPart(Assembly.Load("Gestair.API"))
             .AddControllersAsServices()
             .AddFluentValidation(options =>
             {
                 options.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<ApplicationValidations>(lifetime: ServiceLifetime.Scoped);
                 options.ValidatorFactoryType = typeof(HttpContextServiceProviderValidatorFactory);
             });
        });


        builder.Configure(app =>
        {
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Then, I created the fixture to thest the Authentication controller, for instance.

```
public class AuthenticationControllerFixture : BaseFixture
{
    public IAuthenticationController AuthenticationControllerService;

    public readonly HttpClient _client;
    public readonly BaseFixture _fixture;

    public AuthenticationControllerFixture()
    {
        AuthenticationControllerService = Server.Host.Services.GetRequiredService<IAuthenticationController>();
    }

    public AuthenticateUserDTO CriarUsuarioLogin()
    {
        return new AuthenticateUserDTO()
        {
            Email = "dev@dev.com.br",
            Senha = "123456"
        };
    }
}
```

And then I call the controller function in the test itself:

```
public class AuthenticationControllerTest : IClassFixture<AuthenticationControllerFixture>
{
    private readonly AuthenticationControllerFixture _fixture;

    public AuthenticationControllerTest(AuthenticationControllerFixture fixture)
    {
        _fixture = fixture;
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task ShoudLogin()
    {
        var input = _fixture.CriarUsuarioLogin();

        var response = await _fixture.AuthenticationControllerService.Login(input);
    }
}
```

While debugging, the call is made, it calls the controller but `HttpContext` of the controller that implements that interface, is `null` which is causing error to correctly process the request.

How can I fix this, what am I missing?

Comment: Where are you accessing `HttpContext`?

Comment: @mxmissile Im particularly testing an Authentication endpoint. It is giving this `HttpContext must not be null` exception while trying to execute `PasswordSignInAsync` from `SignInManager`

Comment: Mock or Stub `SignInManager`, that is part of the framework if I recall. You might have to abstract it away with a proxy class and interface.